# New column has to be generated based on an existing column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table in my SQL Server database. I am showing my table with some data in image called input.

[image]

And from this input I want to add one derived column in that column the data should be below format. I am showing my expected output in image called output.

[image]

How can I achieve my expected output with a SQL query?

We have lots of records in the table, but the maximum length of `CODE` column is 4. Means the last value in that column is 9999 only.

Please suggest how I can get my expected output with a simple SQL query.

Best Regards,

Phani Kumar.

Comment: Do you really need a column or just to get the result in that format? (I believe a query might be sufficient, since the data would be a bit .. redundant, between the `code` and `Derived column` columns)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *,
       'C' + RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Code),4) [YourColumn]
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```